# НУЖНО СТАВИТЬ ТИРЕ

Tags: пунктуация

хорошо-бы нам утром встретиться

Comment: Это к чему? Это как?

Answer (score 1):

Хорошо (было) бы нам утром встретиться.

Частица БЫ пишется или слитно в составе союзов (чтобы), или **раздельно**, обычно образуя сослагательное наклонение глагола.

Предложение безличное, сказуемое составное глагольное,  вспомогательная часть выражена предикативным наречием "хорошо" с пропущенной связкой "было" (к этой связке относится частица БЫ).